# Method not working when called from a different Module

Tags: python, kivy-language, kivymd

I have the `Mainmenu.py` Module with Main Screen, `login.py` module with login Screen and `main.py` module with the `MDApp` class. Now I have a method within `Mainmenu.py` that updates the `NavigationDrawer` content, if I call this method within the Main Screen it works perfectly fine, but I want to call it from login Screen, so once the user logs in it updates the navigational drawer, but when I call it from `login.py` it does not do anything.

This is the code within `MainMenu.py` that works when called within the same module:

```
def onlogin_func(self):
    self.my_mdlist = self.ids.md_list
    self.login_item = self.ids.login
    get_item_position = self.my_mdlist.children.index(self.login_item)
    self.ids.md_list.remove_widget(self.login_item)
    self.account_item = OneLineIconListItem(
        IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch(
            icon="account"
            ), 
        text="Cont Personal"
        )
    self.logout_item = OneLineIconListItem(
        IconLeftWidgetWithoutTouch(
            icon="logout"
            ), 
        text="Iesire",
        on_release=lambda x: self.onlogout_fun()
        )
    self.ids.md_list.add_widget(self.account_item, index=get_item_position)
    self.ids.md_list.add_widget(self.logout_item)
```

I have imported "`from MainMenu import MainScreen`" within my `login.py` and created an instance:

```
def test_func_a(self):
        self.main_menu = MainScreen()
        self.main_menu.onlogin_func()
        self.switch_to_main()
```

Now I have a button within `login.py` which calls the `root.test_func_a()`, When I press it nothing happens, it does go back to the main menu, but the NVD is not updated, and the only thing that is doing is updating the Terminal with the following thing:

```
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event9
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event9>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
```

How can I achieve the behavior that I want ?

Comment: So I have added a print statement to the def onlogin_func(self):
and when I call it from login.py the statement is printed on the terminal but the code still did not update the NavigationalDrawer elements.